# How to prevent rive(flare) animations get pixelated on safari?

Tags: flutter, rive, canvaskit

I have a Rive animation in flutter project for the web, the render for the web is Canvaskit, but the animation gets pixelated on the Safari browser.

here is the code to play the simple animation:

```
Container(
       width: 450,
       height: 450,
       child: RiveAnimation.asset(
       'assets/animations/finger.riv',
       antialiasing: true,
       fit: BoxFit.cover,
         ),
```

I tried to change all properties for the widget but it doesn't fix the issue.
The animation works perfectly on iOS, Android, Windows and chrome, the problem is only on safari.

[image: here is how it gets pixelated]

Comment: did you try on chrome

Comment: Yes, it works perfectly on other platforms and browsers.